# How can I invoke a method and print its result?

Tags: java, methods

How can I invoke a method and print its result?

```
public class Test {

    public static int main (String args[]){

        System.out.println(total);

    }

    public int numbers (int a, int b){

        int total;
        total = a + b;
        return = total;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `System.out.println(numbers(someNumber, anotherNumber));`. And you made an error writing `return = total;` instead of `return total;`. Furthermore, your method needs to be `static` unless you want to create an object of type `Test`.

Comment: Off the topic - tutorials are good for learning some things, but when it comes to learning the language itself, I would suggest that you read a good book like *"Java - A Beginner's Guide" by Herbert Schildt*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main (String args[]){

        System.out.println(numbers(1, 2));

    }

    public static int numbers(int a, int b){

        int total;
        total = a + b;
        return total;
    }
}
```

Variables are scoped to the method or class in which they are defined, therefore the 'total' variable is accessible only in the 'numbers' method

Comment: The `static` keyword is necessary: `public static int numbers(int a, int b)`

Comment: Why not `return a+b`?

Comment: i change int to void in the second line of code and it work. thank you.

Comment: @Mixalis That is something we all missed. It *always* has to be `public static void main`.

Answer (score -2):

public class Test {

```
public static void main (String args[]){

    System.out.println(numbers(anumber,bnumber));  

}

public static int numbers (int a, int b){

    int total;
    total = a + b;
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to format your answer properly. Also provide an explanation for the code you present. Explain why their attempt failed and why yours is correct.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Im sory i was in a hury .Anyway thank u for your advise ,im new to this ,so thank u for taking ur time and advising me